# How to reload JqGrid grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a  on my page with semesters as a selection option.
When a semester is selected a JavaScript function is called passing as parameter the id semester.

```
<select name="semester" id="semester" onchange="getStudents(this)">
 <option value="1">Semester 1</option>
 <option value="2">Semester 2</option>
</select>
```

And my jqGrid has the following

```
function getStudents(semester) {
    var $table= $("#students_list");
    $table.jqGrid({
      url:'getStudents/?semester='+semester,
      datatype: "json",
      mtype: 'POST',
      colNames:['id','Student','Semester'],
      colModel:[
        {name:'studentId'},
        {name:'studentName'},
        {name:'semester'}
     ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true
    });         
}
```

But I can only see the results the first time when I call getStudents function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I shows the errors in your current code.

You use `onchange="getStudents(this)`. It means that the parameter of `getStudents` will be initialized with DOM element of the select `#semester`. It means that you need use `$(semester).val()` to get the value of selected option inside of `getStudents` function instead of usage just `semester` (see `'getStudents/?semester='+semester`).

The next problem is the following. The code `$table.jqGrid({...});` **creates the grid**. The empty table `<table id="students_list"></table>` will be converted to relatively complex structure of dives and tables during creating the grid. Because of that one can't make the same call at the second time. Such call will be just ignored. Instead of that one have to destroy the grid by usage of `$("#students_list").jqGrid("GridUnload");` or better to create the grid ones and to reload it later.

You use `mtype: 'POST'` option in jqGrid. It means thet jqGrid use HTTP POST to send some parameters to the server and place there in the body of the HTTP request. It's recommended to send custom parameter `semester` in the same way. In the case you can use

```
var $table = $("#students_list");
$table.jqGrid({
    url: "getStudents",
    datatype: "json",
    mtype: "POST",
    postData: {
        semester: function () {
            return $("#semester").val(); // 1 or 2 from value attr of option
        }
    },
    colNames: ["id", "Student", "Semester"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "studentId"},
        {name: "studentName"},
        {name: "semester"}
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true
});
```

The code will *always* send the current value of `semester` select to the server. For example if the user will click on the column header to sort by it of to click on the next page button then new request with *the current* selected `semester` will be sent to the server. I'd recommend you to read [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) which describes the usage of functions in `postData` more detailed.

To refresh the grid content immediately after changing the option one can use `change` handle which trigger `reloadGrid`:

```
$("#semester").change(function () {
    $table.trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

If you do need to place selected semester in the URL then you should remove `postData` parameter from the option used during creating the grid and to use the following code in `change` event handler:

```
$("#semester").change(function () {
    $table.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
        url: "getStudents/?semester=" + encodeURIComponent($("#semester").val())
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");
});
```

Comment: I did as expected, but it not worked. See my code.
[Code](http://www.codeshare.io/8xW7r)

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares: You posted only the same code which I included. Where is the `<select id="semester" ...`? Where are the test data? Do you have a life demo which have some problems? If you wrote: "it not worked" that you should write **what is not worked**? Do you validate using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox which HTTP traffic you have now? Can you see `semester` data inside or what is not work?

Comment: It is calling only the first time when the page loads, but when I click on select nothing happens.

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares: You should place `$("#semester").change(function () {...})` **inside of** `$(document).ready(function () {...});`

Comment: I use firebug, it shows me the HTTP request returns JSON only the first time, but when I click the select is not made any request

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares: I still don't see *the real code which you use*. Do you placed `<script>` inside of `<head>` of the page and `<select name="semester" id="semester">...<>` and `<table id="students_list"></table>` inside of `<body>`?

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares: You can use JSFiddle for example to provide the demo. Look at this one http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0fvajwhp/ for example which shows how to use `url: "/echo/json/", // use JSFiddle echo service` of JSFiddle

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, in jsFiddle worked. I'll check my code to see what is happening.
http://jsfiddle.net/t9ehx142/1/

Comment: @GleydsonS.Tavares: It should be so. I recommend you to add `height: "auto", autoencode: true` options additionally, but it's independent from your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$table.trigger('reloadGrid');` inside `getStudents()` function.. and don't add jqGrid code inside `getStudents()` function add it on document ready (means page when loaded). Also inside the `jqGrid` code fetch the `ID` of selected item dynamically rather than passing as a parameter.like below:

> url:'getStudents/?semester='+$("#semester").val(),

Comment: Or try only changing this line only "url:'getStudents/?semester='+$("#semester").val()," it should also work in ur case.

Comment: I did as expected, but it not worked. See my code.
[Code](http://www.codeshare.io/8xW7r)

Comment: check for the console using firebug. On changing the select box value is it printing any error or what. Sorry codeshare is blocked for me So,I cant check ur code.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this...

```
function getStudents(semester) {
    var $table= $("#students_list");
    $table.jqGrid({
      url:'getStudents/?semester='+semester,
      datatype: "json",
      mtype: 'POST',
      colNames:['id','Student','Semester'],
      colModel:[
        {name:'studentId'},
        {name:'studentName'},
        {name:'semester'}
     ],
    viewrecords: true,
    gridview: true
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");         
}
```

add `trigger("reloadGrid")` at the end

Hope this help!!!